# How to temporary lock a database in mysql

Tags: mysql, locking

I am using Engine InnoDB on my MySQL server.

I have a patch script to upgrade my tables like add new columns and fill in default data.

I want to make sure there is no other session using the database. So I need a way to lock the database:

1. The lock shouldn't kick out an existing session. If their is any other existing session just fail the lock and report error
2. The lock need to prevent other sessions to read/write/change the database.

Thanks a lot everyone!

Comment: If you are worried about consistency/concurrency issues, MySQL will lock the tables automatically to prevent this. Could you explain what you're trying to accomplish? Why do you want to lock the tables?

Comment: Thanks. Just data consistency. I don't want anything else accessing the database when I am adding columns.

Comment: The database will be kept consistent without any need for manual locking.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't need to worry about locking tables yourself. As the MySQL documentation (http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/alter-table.html) says:

> In most cases, ALTER TABLE makes a temporary copy of the original
>   table. MySQL waits for other operations that are modifying the table,
>   then proceeds. It incorporates the alteration into the copy, deletes
>   the original table, and renames the new one. While ALTER TABLE is
>   executing, the original table is readable by other sessions. Updates
>   and writes to the table that begin after the ALTER TABLE operation
>   begins are stalled until the new table is ready, then are
>   automatically redirected to the new table without any failed updates.